# How can I lock the scroll to go only in one direction in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

Let's say that we have a window and typically we can scroll up-and-down, left-and-right, and diagonal. In other words I we can scroll down and left at the same time. What I want to do is to scroll only one way at a time. Either up-and-down or left-and-right. I don't want to scroll via the diagonal.

Is that possible in HTML?

Comment: You can use the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` style attributes (with values to control scroll bars on both axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the middle mouse button scrolling, you may put this in the `head` section of your HTML document (be aware that **this actually disables the middle button**):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.onmousedown = window.onmousedown = function (e) {
        if(e.which == 2)
        {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e.preventDefault)
                e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not know of a pure HTML method, but you can check out [Sly Plugin](http://jquer.in/jquery-plugins-for-awesome-scrolling-and-scrollbars-on-websites/sly/) for one-direction scrolling. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you shouldn't be able to scroll in x-direction anyway unless the width of the website exceeds screen size. 
The only way is preventing overflow with CSS `overflow-x: hidden`.

But if the user will have a display, where the content can't fit anymore (smartphone display e.g.) or uses browser zoom, there could be a problem with hidden content...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem these answers are the ones you wanted. I came here asking the same question, looking for an easier way but it seems this will have to do:

```
//When scrolling, execute the "Lock Direction" function lockdir()
<body onscroll="lockdir()">
```

Inside the body (or I suppose the head can also work), add the following script:

```
<script>

    //Scroll Variables 
    var scr = {
        initPos: [0, 0],    //Initial Mouse Position
        cPos: [0, 0],       //Current Mouse Position
        locked: 0,          //A direction is locked
        timeout: 0,         //Scroll timeout counter
    }


    //Lock Direction Function
    function lockdir(){
        scr.timeout = 0;    //Keep scroll counter at 0 while scrolling

        //Get the current mouse position and find difference to initial position
        scr.cPos = [
            document.body.scrollTop, 
            document.body.scrollLeft
        ];
        var dif = [
            Math.abs(cPos[0] - scr.initPos[0]),
            Math.abs(cPos[1] - scr.initPos[1])
        ];


        //If no direction is locked (0), lock direction moved least when scrolling started
        if (scr.locked === 0){

            if (dif[1] > dif[0]){
                scr.locked = 2;     //Lock Vertical Scrolling
            }else{
                scr.locked = 1;     //Lock Horizontal Scrolling
            }

        }


        //Reset Locked Direction to initial value
        if (scr.locked === 1){
            document.body.scrollLeft = scr.initPos[1];
        }else{
            document.body.scrollTop = scr.initPos[0];
        }

    }

    //Cancels Lock if timer exceeds 20 milliseconds
    function cancelLock(){
        if (scr.timeout > 20){
            scr.locked = 0;
            scr.initPos = scr.cPos;
        }

        scr.timeout++;
    }

    window.setInterval(cancelLock, 1);  //Repeats cancel lock
</script>
```